# Firebase Functions cannot update NodeJs version

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

For some reason updating a functions node version doesn't seem to work for me.
The package.json in the functions directory has:

"engines": {
"node": "14"
},

According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version) this appears to be all I need to do. But when I deploy it always stays at Node 10. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Is there maybe a setting in the Google Cloud Console that overrides this?

Here is the output of the cli when deploying:

```
i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring required AP cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing backend/functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged backend/functions (234.32 KB) for uploading
i  pubsub: ensuring required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  scheduler: ensuring required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  scheduler: required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  pubsub: required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: backend/functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function sessions(us-central1)...
✔  functions[sessions(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.
```

Here is the corresponding function in the GCP console:[image]

Comment: Delete the function in the console and try again.  Provide the output of the CLI in your question, along with a screenshot of what you see in the console that doesn't match your expectation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue:

In the `firebase.json` file I had the following config for functions:

```
"functions": {
    "runtime": "nodejs10",
    "source": "backend/functions",
    "ignore": ["*.test.ts", "**/node_modules/**"]
},
```

After removing the "runtime" everything worked as expected.

Comment: I change "runtime": "nodejs12" to "runtime": "nodejs16" in firebase.json